# Wait for non-java-process [winscp, sftp ]to complete file transfer in java

Tags: java, operating-system

How to notify java/jvm that the file is being used by another process which is non-java process[i.e winSCP, C:D etc]. Consider I am transferring the file from my local machine to linux server to tmp directory. This tmp directory watch by java-watch-service when any entry is created[ when the files come to this direcotry *java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE*] in this directory the java will transfer this file to different server. The problem is java-watch-service pick this file as soon as ENTRY_CREATE is created without waiting for complete transfer.

This is working fine any-case of windows may be this is due to transfer-process and jvm process has same parent.